# android out of memory error how can I fixed?

Tags: android

I want to take some data on database and this data gives to arrayadapter and then I put in list view but I see that "out of memory"

infoActivity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.ly_info);
try {
    list_info=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_info);
    dbHelper d = new dbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    liste=d.getAllInfo();
       ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
               infoActivity.this, 
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               liste );
       list_info.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

DbHelper :

```
  public ArrayList getAllInfo()

{
             ArrayList listeInfo = new ArrayList();
            String sql ="SELECT * FROM asd";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
               Cursor c=db.rawQuery(sql, null);

while(c.moveToFirst())
{
    int shortNameColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow ("shortName");
    int longNameColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow ("longName"); 
    String gelenShort=c.getString(shortNameColumnIndex);
    String gelenLong=c.getString(longNameColumnIndex);
    listeInfo.add(gelenShort+": "+gelenLong);
}

return listeInfo;
}
```

Comment: how big is your data? can you send stacktrace?

Comment: I just two data very small but I see this error . Error about my code or something?